# Cell Line With DNMT3a Mutation

Tags: cell-biology, cancer

I am looking for a cell line (preferably hematopoietic) that has an inactivating DNMT3a mutation. I have checked the [Cancer Cell Line Encyclopedia](http://www.broadinstitute.org/ccle/home) but of all the hematopoietic cell lines I know I can't find any with a DNMT3a mutation.

It would be great if somebody knows of a cell line with a DNMT3a mutation, but it would also be helpful if somebody knows of a database that I could use to find this information in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just induce one? There are quite easy-to-use CRISPR/Cas kits available nowadays.

Comment: While that would work, it would be much cheaper and easier to identify which of the cell lines at my disposal contain such a mutation.

Comment: All I'm saying is if you can't find a cell line that meets your needs, it would be quite cost-effective to generate one on your own. There are some extra costs outside of the kit, but [this Life Technologies kit](http://www.lifetechnologies.com/order/catalog/product/A21175) is only US$514, whereas purchasing a new cell line from ATCC not in your collection [may cost](http://www.atcc.org/Products/Cells_and_Microorganisms/Cell_Lines/Human/Alphanumeric.aspx) an approximately equivalent amount, depending on the line, what kind of institution you're at, etc. Worth thinking about.

Comment: For CRISPR-Cas you don't even need the kit. Just have a plasmid for containing the Cas9 gene from where you can IVT the Cas9 mRNA. Co-transfect this with the donor plasmid.

Comment: [Or for only $60 from AddGene](https://www.addgene.org/crispr/)